# Multiple boxplots side by side

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I'm trying to make multiple boxplots with ggplot2 side by side. I've been following the stes [Multiple boxplots placed side by side for different column values in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32103434/multiple-boxplots-placed-side-by-side-for-different-column-values-in-ggplot) but without much luck.

I have the following dataframes

```
Raw <- sp500_logreturns
Normal <- rnorm(1000, 0, sd(sp500_logreturns)
Student <- cbind(c(rt(1000, df = 2)),c(rt(1000, df = 3)))
```

And I want to make the following
[Boxplot sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wA5Ew.png)

My `Raw` vector contains logreturns-transformation of my prices downloaded as an environment from yahoo into R. I must admit I'm quite lost, and do not know if I'm on an impossible mission. I hope I've described my problem well enough together with my sketch. Thank you in advance.

Update 1: The goal is to compare the raw data distribution (which is leptokurtic) and therefore a student disitribution with 2 or 3 degree of freedom might be more suitable than a normal distribution. To give you an idea of the data I'm looking at, here's a summary:

```
      Min.    1st Qu.     Median       Mean    3rd Qu.       Max. 
-0.0418425 -0.0023740  0.0005898  0.0004704  0.0045065  0.0484032
```

Here is my boxplot made from Edward's code: [Boxplot (Edward)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YA7Lj.png)

Update 2: I figured it out. I used `fitdist` from `rugarch` to find out the best student distribution fitted to the raw data. This way I could ignore trying to match different dfs of the student distribution. This is what I will go on with:

```
fitdist(distribution = 'std', sp500_logreturns)$pars
          mu        sigma        shape 
0.0008121004 0.0113748869 2.3848231857 

data <- data.frame(
        Raw = as.numeric(sp500_logreturns),
        Normal = rnorm(1006, 0, sd(sp500_logreturns)),
        Student = rdist(distribution = 'std', n = 1006, mu = 0.0008121004, sigma = 0.0113748869, shape = 2.3848231857)
)

data2 <- pivot_longer(data, cols=everything()) %>%
        mutate(name=factor(name, levels=c("Raw","Normal","Student")))

data3 <- data2 %>% summarise(min=min(value), max=max(value))

pbox1 <- (filter(data2, name %in% c("Raw","Normal","Student")) %>%
        ggplot(aes(y=value, fill=name)) +
        geom_boxplot() +
        facet_grid(~name) +
        ylab("Log-returns") +
        ylim(data3$min, data3$max) +
        theme(legend.position = "none",
              axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
              panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
              panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
              axis.text.x=element_text(color="white"))+
        ggtitle("Boxplot comparison")+
        theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)))
```

And this gives me: [Boxplot (final)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/457U7.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R:

```
set.seed(11)
data <- data.frame(
  Raw = rnorm(1000),
  Normal = rnorm(1000),
  Student = cbind(c(rt(1000, df = 2)),c(rt(1000, df = 3)))
)

ylim=c(min(data), max(data))

layout(matrix(1:3, nc=3), widths=c(5,4,5))
par(las=1, mar=c(2,4,5,0))
boxplot(daat$Raw, col="steelblue", ylab="Log-returns", ylim=ylim)
title(main="Raw", line=1)

par(mar=c(2,1,5,0))
boxplot(data$Normal, yaxt="n", col="tomato", ylim=ylim)
title(main="Normal", line=1)

par(mar=c(2,1,5,1))
boxplot(data[,3:4], yaxt="n", col=c("green1","green3"), names=c("df = 2","df = 3"), ylim=ylim)
title(main="Student", line=1)
title(main="Boxplot comparison", outer=TRUE, line=-1.5, cex.main=1.5)
```

---

[image]

---

In ggplot2, more work is invovled:

```
set.seed(11)
data <- data.frame(
  Raw = rnorm(1000),
  Normal = rnorm(1000),
  Student = cbind(c(rt(1000, df = 2)),c(rt(1000, df = 3)))
)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

data2 <- pivot_longer(data, cols=everything()) %>%
  mutate(name=factor(name, levels=c("Raw","Normal","Student.1","Student.2")))

data3 <- data2 %>% summarise(min=min(value), max=max(value))

p1 <- filter(data2, name %in% c("Raw","Normal")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y=value, fill=name)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_grid(~name) +
  ylab("Log-returns") +
  ylim(data3$min, data3$max) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_text(color="white"))

p2 <- filter(data2, grepl("Student", name)) %>%
  mutate(what="Student") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=name, y=value, fill=name)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("green1","green3")) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("df=2", "df=3")) +
  facet_grid(~what) +
  ylim(data3$min, data3$max) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank())

library(ggpubr)
ggarrange(p1, p2)
```

---

[image]

Comment: You are my hero! But do you know how to convert this into ggplot2, I need to stay consistent in my plots to satisfy my "OCD" :-)

Comment: What is "OCD"?  And could you show me what your desired graph actually looks like? I'd hate to spend an hour on a graph and then find out it wasn't the way you wanted it. :)  *** oh, I figured it out. haha

Comment: I use the standard ggplot-look. I don't know if it makes sense, but just want to transform the graph, that you've made into ggplot-look.

Comment: It's perfect! Thank you Edward, this really helped me moving on with my thesis! Have a nice day :-)

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to load ```ggpubr``` but it wont load. It says "package or namespace load failed for ‘ggpubr’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 namespace ‘tibble’ 2.1.3 is loaded, but >= 3.0.0 is required". But my R wont update ```tibble``` package. Do you know any fix?

Comment: I've seen that here before. I think the solution is to restart R (or maybe even your computer). Open R, then install ggpubr. There are other packages that can arrange ggplots. Try cowplot or patchwork

Comment: One more thing... My log-returns have quite small values. When I plot my data I get totally flat boxplots for my normal and raw data. How to fix this?

Comment: What's the objective of the graphs? Maybe you can remove the `ylim` command and let the axes fit the data. You'll have to add the y-axis to the Student plot, `p2` (omit this line: `axis.ticks.y=element_blank()`). Tell me exactly what you want.

Comment: I've updated once more. This is my final result. Thanks for the help!