# How to make a box plot of one gene from a file in R then apply to all genes

Tags: r, ggplot2

[screenshot of the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/parwi.png)

We can use the first gene "12154451" and make a box plot of all the columns from 2:28.

Once this is figures out, I would like to apply it to all genes.

Thanks

I have tried multiple different functions of ggplot2 but it has not worked.

Comment: Welcome to SO! To make a boxplot of multiple columns you have to reshape your data to long or tidy format, i.e. try `dat |> tidyr::pivot_longer(-gene_symbol) |> ggplot(aes(gene_symbol, value)) + geom_boxplot()` or see [ggplot: Boxplot of multiple column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14785530/ggplot-boxplot-of-multiple-column-values).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We cannot read data into R from images. Please [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including a small representative dataset in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(yourdata)`, if that is not too large.